# Как отобразить скрытый блок

Tags: jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

Добрый день!
Есть меню, при наведении на отчеты необходимо отобразить скрытый блок. Но почему то не срабатывает.

```css
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: ProximaNovaRegular, sans-serif;
 color: #232527;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.block-white {
 max-width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.block-black {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #f2f3f5;
}
.nav li {
 border-right: 1px solid #232527;
 display: inline-block;
}
.nav li:last-child {
 border: none;
 background: url(../img/vk.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}
.nav li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: #232527;
 font-size: 0.875rem;
}
.nav-fill > li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.nav-fill > li:last-child {
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
.nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #d50317;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-hidden {
 font-size: 1rem;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 display: none;
}
.nav-hidden hr {
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #d50317;
 margin-top: 4px;
}
.nav-hidden .conteiner {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.nav-hidden a {
 color: #232527;
}
.nav-hidden a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #d50317;
}
.nav-visible:hover .nav-hidden {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-fill">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">О фонде</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">СМИ о нас</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Наши меценаты</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item nav-visible"><a href="#">Отчеты</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Благодарности</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Помочь Нам</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Наша группа</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-hidden">
 <div class="block-big-white">
  <hr>
  <div class="block-white">
   <div class="conteiner">
    <div class='row'>
     <div class="col-3"><a href="#">Медецинские учреждения</a></div>
     <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Детям</a></div>
     <div class="col-2 offset-2"><a href="#">Другим категориям</a></div>
     <div class="col-3 offset-1"><a href="#">Отчет о фин поступлениях и тратах</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
     <div class="col-3"><a href="#">Социальные учреждения</a></div>
     <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Семьям</a></div>
     <div class="col-3 offset-2"><a href="#">Акты передачи гум помощи</a></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Подключены Bootstrap и jQuery
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? возможно я принципиально что то не то делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь показать элемент div, при наведении на элемент li с помощью css, но эти два элемента никак друг с другом не связаны.
Однако, это можно сделать при помощи jquery. Во-первых, Вам потребуется два класса: `.hidden {aisplay: none}` `.show {aisplay: block}` для элемента nav-hidden, а затем на jqery Вам нужно написать примерно так (хотя это откровенный пипец, но чтобы Вы поняли принцип):

```
 ;(function($, window, document) {
    $('.nav-visible').on('mousemove', function() {

        $('.nav-hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');

    });

    $('.nav-visible').on('mouseout', function() {

        $('.nav-hidden').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');

    });

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

Классы для скрытого элемента:

```
.nav-hidden {
font-size: 1rem;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.hidden {display: none;}

.show {aisplay: block}
```

А вообще, конечно не стоит так писать, лучще было бы реализовать это вложением выпадающего блока в нужный пункт списка основного меню, обошлись бы одним css.
Например, вот так: https://www.mobila.name/post/5172c6cbb4ab3/

======> ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС ИЗ КОММЕНТАРИЯ
Мне правда стыдно за этот код, перепишу еще по человечески, но пока так:

```
;(function($, window, document) {
$('.nav-visible').on('mouseover', function() {


    $('.nav-hidden').css('display', 'block')
            .animate({opacity:1}, 400);
});

$('.hidden').on('mouseleave', function() {


    $(this).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 100).css('display', 'none');
    });

});

$('.someClassInNav').on('mouseover', function() {


    $('.nav-hidden').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 100).css('display', 'none');
    });
});

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

класс для скрытого элемента (классы show и hidden из прошлого варианта нужно удалить):

```
.nav-hidden {
font-size: 1rem;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
opacity: 0;
display: none;
}
```

И нужно добавить еще класс для навигации:

```
<ul class="nav nav-fill">
    <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">О фонде</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">СМИ о нас</a></li>
    <li class="someClassInNav"><a href="#">Наши меценаты</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-visible"><a href="#">Отчеты</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">Благодарности</a></li>
    <li class="someClassInNav"><a href="#">Помочь Нам</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">Наша группа</a></li>
</ul>
```

Целиковый код.

```js
;(function($, window, document) {
 $('.nav-visible').on('mouseover', function() {
  

  $('.nav-hidden').css('display', 'block')
                .animate({opacity:1}, 400);
 });

 $('.hidden').on('mouseleave', function() {
 

  $(this).fadeOut(300, function() {
   $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 100).css('display', 'none');
  });

 });
 
 $('.someClassInNav').on('mouseover', function() {
  

  $('.nav-hidden').fadeOut(300, function() {
   $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 100).css('display', 'none');
  });
 });

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

```css
body {
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: ProximaNovaRegular, sans-serif;
color: #232527;
background-color: #fff;}

.block-white {
max-width: 1170px;
margin: 0 auto;}

.block-black {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #f2f3f5;}

.nav li {
border-right: 1px solid #232527;
display: inline-block;}

.nav li:last-child {
border: none;
}

.nav li a {
padding: 10px 20px;
color: #232527;
font-size: 0.875rem;}

.nav-fill>li:first-child  {
text-align: left;
padding-left: 0px;}

.nav-fill>li:last-child  {
text-align: right;
padding-right: 30px;}

.nav li a:hover {
background-color: #d50317;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;}

.nav-hidden {
font-size: 1rem;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
opacity: 0;
display: none;
}


.nav-hidden hr {
height: 3px;
background-color: #d50317;
margin-top: 4px;}

.nav-hidden .conteiner {
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;}

.nav-hidden a {
color: #232527;}

.nav-hidden a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #d50317;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="css.css" />

</head>

<body>

<ul class="nav nav-fill">
        <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">О фонде</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">СМИ о нас</a></li>
        <li class="someClassInNav"><a href="#">Наши меценаты</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-visible"><a href="#">Отчеты</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">Благодарности</a></li>
        <li class="someClassInNav"><a href="#">Помочь Нам</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item someClassInNav"><a href="#">Наша группа</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-hidden hidden">
    <div class="block-big-white">
        <hr>
        <div class="block-white">
            <div class="conteiner">
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class="col-3"><a href="#">Медецинские учреждения</a></div>
                    <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Детям</a></div>
                    <div class="col-2 offset-2"><a href="#">Другим категориям</a></div>
                    <div class="col-3 offset-1"><a href="#">Отчет о фин поступлениях и тратах</a></div>
                </div>
                <di class='row'>
                    <div class="col-3"><a href="#">Социальные учреждения</a></div>
                    <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Семьям</a></div>
                    <div class="col-3 offset-2"><a href="#">Акты передачи гум помощи</a></div>
                </di>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению не представляю как это реализовать с помощью вложенных списков, т.к нужно что бы сам текст как основного меню так и вложенного был одной ширины, а вот оформление вложенного блока, а именно тень от него должна идти на всю длину браузера. За ответ спасибо, помог.

Comment: На вскидку, могу предложить в качестве тянущегося блока и тени от него использовать псевдоэлементы, но нужно поиграть со стилями. Хотя, не вижу ничего страшного в использовании js.

Comment: А не подскажите как еще организовать появление и исчезновение этого блока в момент наведения или снятия наведения? А то выходит очень резкая смена. Я пробовал fadeToggle применить, но к сожалению ничего у меня не вышло.  Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дописал в ответ

Comment: К сожалению не работает данные исправления. $('.nav-hidden').css('display', 'block') добавляет блок на страницу, но он не появляется.

Comment: css тоже изменили как написал? удалили из него классы hidden и show?

Comment: да, css подчистил!

Comment: Я добавил полный код в ответ, посмотри, может где-то что-то мешает, потому как у меня работает. Проверь.

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо! Есть еще один один момент: при появлении этого скрытого блока контент который идет под ним сдвигается, вопрос в следующем можно ли сделать так чтобы скрытый блок .nav-hidden не двигал последующий контент а накладывался сверху него? А то выглядят эти прыжки не очень!

Comment: Нужно задать ему `position: absolut;`, а родительскому элементу `position: relative;` ну и дальше спозиционировать скрытый блок top'ом и left'ом.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `<li class="nav-item nav-visible">` не является [пра]родителем `<div class="nav-hidden">`, по-этому `.nav-visible:hover .nav-hidden {...}` применяться к нему не будет. Перенесите `<div class="nav-hidden">` непосредственно в `<li class="nav-item nav-visible">` или используйте `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

**Это для примера** ( без bootstrap ), если элемент вне какого то блока то его можно вызвать на js/jquery

```js
$(".con span").click(function() {
  $(".generick").addClass("show");
  $("js").addClass("show");
});


$("js").click(function() {
  $(".generick").removeClass("show");
  $(this).removeClass("show");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 400;
}

.link span {
  color: blue;
}

.link:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.generick {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 300;
  background: #fff;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

js {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 90;
  display: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="menu">
  <div class="link"><span>О нас</span></div>
  <div class="link"><span>Прайс</span></div>
  <div class="link"><span>Врачи</span></div>
  <div class="link con"><span>Консультации</span></div>
  <div class="generick">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-3"><a href="#">Медецинские учреждения</a></div>
      <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Детям</a></div>
      <div class="col-2 offset-2"><a href="#">Другим категориям</a></div>
      <div class="col-3 offset-1"><a href="#">Отчет о фин поступлениях и тратах</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-3"><a href="#">Социальные учреждения</a></div>
      <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Семьям</a></div>
      <div class="col-3 offset-2"><a href="#">Акты передачи гум помощи</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="link"><span>Галерея</span></div>
  <div class="link"><span>Наша группа</span></div>
</div>
<js></js>
```